# How can i convert seconds into date format in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The code is as below my Start_DateVal has the selected date and from the datepicker .And i am trying to alert the date which is 8 months ahead from the selected date (Start_DateVal).

```
function ChangeEndDate() 
{
var Start_DateVal = document.getElementById("Start_Date").value;

if(Start_DateVal!='')
    {
        var arr=Start_DateVal.split("-");
        var day= arr[0];
        var month= arr[1];
        var year= arr[2];

        var d = new Date(year, month, day);
        var InSeconds=d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 8);
         alert(InSeconds);  //Here i wanted to display in date format instead of seconds.
    }

}
```

Problem Statement: i am getting the alert in Seconds (InSeconds) Variable .But how do i convert Seconds into DD-MM-YYYY  Date Format.Please Help me Thank you.

Comment: FYI: It's not seconds, it's milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var d = new Date(2017, 01, 12);
var date = d.getDate();
var month = d.getMonth()+1; 
var year = d.getFullYear();

if(date<10){
date='0'+date;
} 
if(month<10){
month='0'+month;
} 

alert(date + '-' + month + '-' + year)
```